# How to use JavaScript's "apply" method with an extra parameter before the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to modify some existing JavaScript code which used [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass an array to a member function normally expecting any number of parameters:

```
oldFoo: function( arg /* , ..., argN */ ) {
  ...
}

var ary = ...

oldFoo.apply($, ary)

... other stuff using ary ...
```

The new code still takes any number of parameters and I still have them as an array to pass in, but I also need to pass in a new parameter before the array

```
newFoo: function( someObject, arg /* , ..., argN */ ) {
  ...
}

var ary = ...

newFoo.apply($, ???, ary)

... other stuff using ary ...
```

So I know I can make a new version of `ary` with array methods which modify it in-place such as `pop`/`push`/`shift`/`unshift` but I want to do various things with my array so don't want to modify it in place.

I know I can build a new temporary array by prepending `someObject` to it, but that seems to take several lines of code each time.

Is there a more expressive way to achieve what I want to do in about the same number of lines? Something I'm missing about `apply` or about array functions which return a new array rather than modifying one in-place? I'm already using jQuery so if it has something useful that vanilla JavaScript doesn't have then that's great too.

Comment: `apply($, ???, ary)` won't work prepending (or appending) is you're only option I guess.. @David gives a good example ;)

Comment: @VDP: The `???` was my handwaving for "no idea what really happens somewhere around here" (-:

Comment: @David: I accept everything I've been able to test but many things I haven't been in a position to go through with yet and I don't like to accept just due to pressure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do:

```
newFoo.apply($, ['foo','bar'].concat(ary) );
```

That way you won’t modify any existing array of arguments. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> concat creates a new array consisting of the elements in the this
>   object on which it is called, followed in order by, for each argument,
>   the elements of that argument (if the argument is an array) or the
>   argument itself (if the argument is not an array).

Comment: So I guess in my example that would be `newFoo.apply($, [ options ].concat(ary))`?

Comment: @hippietrail If `options` is an array, you just need `options.concat(ary)`. If you don’t want to modify `options`, try `options.slice().concat(ary)`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry `options` is an object, I didn't realize my example didn't reveal that.

Comment: OK, then just do `[options].concat(ary)` and you will bring the entire object into the `newFoo` as first argument.